# Unable to view the date and time in Motox

Tags: java, android, date, time

I am developing an app in which i want to display the date and time the code works fine in other devices except in motox.I don't know where the problem is.

```
public static String convertDateTimeForm(Context context,String date){
String date_tim=date;
 //date_tim=date.toString().replaceAll("\\.","");
 //date_tim=date_tim.replaceAll("AM","am").replaceAll("PM","pm");
 String newTime="";
 try{
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=null;
 dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm a");
  simpleDateFormat convertFormat;
  convertFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  Date newDate=null;
 newDate=dateFormat.parse(date_tim);
 newTime=convertFormat.format(newDate);
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
return newTime;
}
```

Comment: it works fine in rest of the device my client has told that it didn't works in his phone

Comment: check that device and watch on logcat error/warnings.